# VBA Programming to recognise a pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help on this. Okay, as example i have data in excel and this is only a part of them:

Temp : (21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 29, 30, 26 25, 24, 23, 22), (24, 25, 26, 30, 27, 28, 29, 25, 21, 19), (20, 22, 23, 36,30, 34, 35, 30, 25, 23), (24, 26, 30, 34, 28, 25, 20)

These are temperature of a liquid. The temperature are increasing until the peak and then go down until certain temperature (one cycle). 
Then it is increasing and goes down again(next cycle). In these example there are 4 cycles.
And it repeats until i have a few cycles. 
For every **each of the temperature**, i can calculate its volume. 
I try to write code to detect these cycles because i want to calculate the average volume **for each cycle**. 
But i don't have idea how to start since i am new to VBA.

Thank you

Comment: Give us an example of how you calculate volume for a **single** cycle.

Comment: The way you define the problem it seems that a cycle starts whenever there is a temperature increase after a temperature decrease. Is that true? Your second and third cycles does no follow this pattern (temperature increases, then decreases, then increases then decreases again). Can you specify how many times a temperature is allowed to increase and decrease within any cycle?

Comment: How's your data written? In one cell or 1 reading per cell or how you wrote it with comma(,)  as delimiter?

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I really appreciate. The pattern for a cycle is normally "increase and then decrease". Next cycle begin when the temperature start to increase again. Above is just an example where you can see in the () is one cycle. Sometimes there will be a slight decrease and increase in a cycle but the value is very small like 0.01. I want to attach a picture so that you guys can see clearly, but i dont have enough reputation. I arrange my data according to column. Lets say column A is for Temperature, B for Volume, C for Density, D for Power and etc.

Comment: At the end i want to calculate the average value of temperature, volume, power and etc in a single cycle. Something like this: Average Temp = (Sum of Temp in a cycle)/(Number of Temp).. As in the above example, for cycle 1 : AverageTemp = (320)/13 = 24.6

Comment: No one can help until you answer L42's question.  Is the entire string in a single cell?  Is each ( ... ) in a single cell?  Is each temperature in a single cell.  Are the cells in a single column?

Comment: Sorry. I hope this is more clear. I arrange each temperature in a single cell and the cells in a single column. Lets say column A for Temperature and i have 100 data of temperature. From A1 to A100, each single cell contain only one temperature. The same for the other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Before iamge of data]

The screen shot above shows that I have placed your data in column 1 of worksheet Sheet1.  I have coloured cells to help me check my macro identifies the cycles correctly; the macro neither sets nor uses these colours.

Starting in cell A2, the macro searches for a peak value and then searches for a trough value which identifies a cycle.    It then loops to identify the next cycle.  This continues until the list is exhausted.

You do not say how you want each cycle to be marked so I have chosen an approach which might be acceptable.  You can see from the screen shot below, I have copied each cycle to a row starting in column “G”.  I do not know your volume calculation, so I have placed the string `Vol(n)` as a place holder.  You will need to replace this with the appropriate formula.  The average is the average temperature; the comments tell you how to change this to average volume.

[image: After image of data]

I hope this gets you started.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitByCycle()

  Dim ColDestAverage As Long
  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
  Dim ColDestTempFirst As Long
  Dim ColDestTitle As Long
  Dim ColSrc As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcStartCycle As Long
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
  Dim VolumeCrnt As Double
  Dim VolumeTotal As Double

  ' Assume data starts in A2
  RowSrcCrnt = 2
  ColSrc = 1

  ' Output cycles starting from Row 2
  RowDestCrnt = 2
  ColDestTitle = 5
  ColDestAverage = 6
  ColDestTempFirst = 7

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    .Cells(RowDestCrnt - 1, ColDestAverage).Value = "Average"

    Do While True

      ' Record start of current cycle
      RowSrcStartCycle = RowSrcCrnt

      ' Search for cycle peak
      Do While True
        RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt + 1
        If .Cells(RowSrcCrnt - 1, ColSrc).Value > _
           .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrc).Value Then
          ' The last cell is greater than current cell so last cell was peak
          Exit Do
        End If
        ' Temperatures are still rising.  Continue search for peak
      Loop

      ' Search for cycle end
      Do While True
        RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt + 1
        If .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrc).Value = "" Or _
           .Cells(RowSrcCrnt - 1, ColSrc).Value < _
           .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrc).Value Then
          ' Either the end of the list of temperature has been reached or
          ' the last cell is less than the current cell.  Either way, the
          ' last cell is the end of the cycle
          Exit Do
        End If
        ' Temperatures are still falling.  Continue search for minimum
      Loop

      ' RowSrcStartCycle is the start of the current cycle
      ' RowSrcCrnt - 1   is the end of the current cycle

      ' Move current cycle to next destination row
      .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestTitle).Value = "Temperatures"
      .Range(.Cells(RowSrcStartCycle, ColSrc), _
             .Cells(RowSrcCrnt - 1, ColSrc)).Copy
       .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestTempFirst).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
                                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
      RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1

      ' Calculate volumes
      VolumeTotal = 0#
      .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestTitle).Value = "Volumes"
      For ColDestCrnt = ColDestTempFirst To _
                        ColDestTempFirst + RowSrcCrnt - RowSrcStartCycle - 1
        VolumeCrnt = .Cells(RowDestCrnt - 1, ColDestCrnt).Value   ' Replace with calculation.  ######
        ' Replace "Vol(" & .Cells(RowDestCrnt - 1, ColDestCrnt).Value & ")"
        ' with VolumnCrnt.  ######
        .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt).Value = _
                   "Vol(" & .Cells(RowDestCrnt - 1, ColDestCrnt).Value & ")"
        VolumeTotal = VolumeTotal + VolumeCrnt
      Next

      ' Calculate average
      .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestAverage).Value = _
                          VolumeTotal / (RowSrcCrnt - RowSrcStartCycle)

      RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 2

      If .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrc).Value = "" Then
        ' Have reach end of list of temperatures
        Exit Do
      End If

      ' RowSrcCrnt is the first temperature of the next cycle

    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @user3739106   I am pleased it helps.  I would be grateful if you accepted the answer by clicking the outline tick.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Thank you very much and i have clicked the outline tick